# Derivative of $\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I don't understand how to calculate $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial \bar{z}}{\partial z}}$.

I read this is zero, but I don't understand why. If I use the Cauchy riemann equations, I find

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \bar{z}}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial\bar{z}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (x-iy)}{\partial x}=1 \neq 0
\end{align*}

So I don't understand$\cdots$

Comment: $z \mapsto \bar z$  it not complex differentiable, it does not satisfy the CR equations.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable

Comment: To the editor: Do you really think that “I don't understand$\cdots$“ looks better than “I don't understand ...”? This is *text,* not maths.

Comment: Thank you all!!